# Can a simple adapter connect a SATA device directly to the PCIe bus?

Tags: sata, pci-express, adapter

While looking for an easy and inexpensive way to add one more SATA connector in my computer I came across [this PCI Express to SATA Adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-HOT-PCI-e-PCI-Express-to-SATA-Adapter-Converter-Card-Mini-/170656767275):

[image]
[image]

It has no electronics on it, just PCB traces that connect some of the PCIe signal traces to its female SATA connector. Every other PCIe SATA adapter I've seen has some electronics on it, but they also support more than one SATA device.

Is it possible to connect a SATA device directly to the PCI Express bus using only a basic adapter without logic circuitry? Asked differently, does the PCIe specification support SATA natively?

Comment: Seems to me you'd need a SATA controller somewhere in the mix.

Comment: The description the product explains what it is, go read it, it is very clear.

Comment: Ramhound, the product description is full of multiple obvious mistakes/misstatements (e.g., says it supports two SATA devices, but it clearly has only one set of terminals; says it fits mini PCIe, but clearly shows a regular size PCIe connector) ... which is why I'm inquiring of anyone who understands operation of PCIe and SATA sufficiently that they can comment on whether this device should work.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some Googling and found this [product](http://www.hwtools.net/Adapter/PM362.html).  You can clearly see a chip on the printed circuit board (PCB).  I can only assume that is a SATA controller, which is required for the computer to talk to the SATA devices.

The one pictured in the question does *not* have a SATA controller wouldnt work.

Comment: *"I would assume the device that you linked to has the SATA controller chip on the other (hidden) side of the PCB"* -- Incorrect assumption.

Comment: well that answers that.  It wont work.  Changing my answer.